# How to find the character position of something specified with a <tag>...</>? Python

Tags: python, xml, tags

I am trying to get the position of the `<` and `>` that are real`tag` when they are embedded in something like this `<tag "510270">calculate</>`.

I have sentences like these:

```
sentence = "After six weeks and seventeen tentative approaches the only serious 
tender came from Daniel. He had offered a paltry #2 a week for the one-time 
woodman's home, sane enough in this, at least, to <tag "510270">calculate</> 
safety to the nearest new penny piece. "

sentence2 = "After six weeks and seventeen tentative approaches the only serious 
tender came from Daniel. He had offered a paltry #2 a week for the one-time 
woodman's < home, sane enough in this, at least, to <tag "510270">calculate</> 
safety to the nearest new penny > piece. "

sentence3 = "After six weeks and seventeen tentative approaches the only serious 
tender came from Daniel. He had offered a paltry #2 a week for the one-time 
woodman's > home, sane enough in this, at least, to <tag "510270">calculate</> 
safety to the nearest new penny < piece. "
```

I need the cfrom and incfrom to be position of the 1st and 2nd `<` within the `<tag "XXXX">...</>` and I need the cto and incto to be position of the 2nd and 1st `>` within the `<tag "XXXX">...</>`

How could i do it also for sentences like sentence2 and sentence3, where `<` or `>` occurs outside of the `<tag "XXXX">...</>`?

For sentence1, i could simply do this:

```
cfrom,cto = 0,0
for i,c in enumerate(sentence1):
  if c == "<":
    cfrom == i
  break

for i,c in enumerate(sentence1.reverse):
  if c == ">":
    cto == len(sentence)-i
  break

incfrom incto = 0,0
fromtrigger, totrigger = False, False
for i,c in enumerate(sentence1[cfrom:]):
  if c == ">":
    incfrom = cfrom+i
  break

for i,c in enumerate(sentence1[incfrom:cto]):
  if c == "<":
    incto = i
  break
```

Comment: insteag of searching for "<", search for "<tag". And for the ">" have another check which looks for "<tag" before it finds ">"

Comment: you still run to the same problem with `>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about something like the following where you keep track of where you are when you find the tag:

```
def parseSentence(sentence):
    cfrom, cto, incfrom, incto = 0, 0, 0, 0
    place = '' #to keep track of where we are

    for i in range(len(sentence)):
        c = sentence[i]
        if (c == '<'):
            #check for 'cfrom'
            if (sentence[i : i + 4] == '<tag'):
                cfrom = i
                place = 'botag' #begin-open-tag
            #check for 'incfrom'
            elif (sentence[i + 1] == '/' and place == 'intag'):
                incfrom = i
                place = 'bctag' #begin-close-tag
        elif (c == '>'):
            #check for 'cto'
            if (place == 'botag'): #just after '<tag...'
                cto = i
                place = 'intag' #now within the XML tag
            #check for 'incto'
            elif (place == 'bctag'):
                incto = i
                place = ''
                yield (cfrom, cto, incfrom, incto)
```

This should work correctly for all your sentences<strike>, but note that it will really only work correctly if there is only one `<tag>...</>` in your sentence. If there are more than one it will return the positions of the last `<tag>...</>`.</strike>

**Edit:**  If you add a `yield` into the function it will iterate over the positions of all `<tag>...</>` tags in your sentence if you have more than one (see above).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand this correctly, this should work (assuming you dont change the variables `i ,c`)

```
cfrom,cto = 0,0
for i,c in enumerate(sentence1):
  if c == "<tag":
    cfrom == i 
  break

for i,c in enumerate(sentence1):
  if c == ">":
    cto == i \\going forward from cfrom
  break

incfrom incto = 0,0
fromtrigger, totrigger = False, False
for i,c in enumerate(sentence1[cto:]):\\after the tag is opened, look for the start of closing tag
  if c == "</":
    incfrom = i
  break
for i,c in enumerate(sentence1[cto:]):
  if c == ">":
    incto = i
  break
```

Comment: i guess it works for the dataset as it is now. I still think there should be some other more elegant way to do this =)